# Authorization header with Volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

i am coming to you with the following issue and questions.

I am trying to achieve sending a request with use of Volley library basing on a example request:

> POST /oauth2/token?code=pP5J8YN8&grant_type=authorization_code
>
> Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50X2lkOnNlY3JldA==

So i am trying to add a authorization header with the following code:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String,String>();


                    headers.put("Authorization", "Basic" + base64 );


                    System.out.println(headers);
                    return headers;

                }
```

The problem is that all i get from the server is :

BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for....

That would mean that my header construction is not proper, what i have noticed with printing that header i receive:

"{Authorization=Basic Y1cxdUNQeUtKamFWbWJBcGRsTHZKNkNvbm9DcDg0dkE6VEl0Wk12WjBvRWhJU2RFZA==}"

is it correct that there is "=" instead of ":" sign?
What am i missing here ?

Comment: you are implemented right if you print hash-map it's will print `{key=value,key=value}` . `500` error is internal server error and it's not in app side

Comment: is your api working on postman? and `base64` has space`(" Y1cxd..")` on start?

Comment: @RajasekaranM The base64 doesn't have space on start, i am not sure it can be on the server side, what i am trying to reach here is to get proper communication for exchanging tokens with Philips HUE remote API. And on their website the description of the code 500 is:
 Check content of Authorisation header, should be: "Basic: <base64(clientid:clientsecret)>"

Comment: So add space after `Basic`. Ex : `Basic <your base 64 value>`